# What happen if I delete mongodb database files?

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

Here is my problem, I'm working with my own test VM on a data transformation project with Talend & Mongodb. Unfortunately I tried launching a Map/Reduce operation on a huge scale with apparently too few space available on disk. It crashed.

(I loaded in a single collection data from a 2Go csv file, it created a 9Go db, I thought this was just allocated space, and that my next operations wouldn't have make it bigger again... Then aggregated some in a new collection with a Map/Reduce script.)

Now I can't open the mongo shell, even if I force delete the lock file due to, apparently, a damaged database file. And the repair command on launch of mongodb fails due to insufficient disk space (10Go database files, needs the same amout of disk space, only have 2Go).

I want to totally get rid of the db to start over with sampled data, so basically I wan't to drop the db without being able to use the shell... can I just delete the files dbname.1 to dbname.8 and dbname.ns ? It seems a bit violent...

Thanks for your help!

edit : Solved my issue, starting mongod with --nojournal, but still interested about how mongodb would deal with these files being deleted

Comment: If you delete all the data files, you will lose all the data and it will be like a fresh MongoDB instance. In MongoDB 2.6, to get rid of one database you can delete all of its associated files and it shouldn't affect the data from the other databases.

Comment: Nice, I was afraid to ommit a file listing the databases in the instance or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you delete ALL the files associated with a database it should be mostly ok. Because of reasons I had to do this and nothing exploded in my face.  this is of course NOT the optimal solution, but nothing should hopefully melt if you do